# Rearranging and aggregating columns in a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Input:

```
original_matrix =
[
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
]

transformation =
[
    [0, 2],
    [1, 4],
    [3, 6, 7]
]
```

Output:

```
transformed_matrix =
[
    [2, 0, 2],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [0, 2, 0],
    [1, 1, 1]
]
```

Let me explain what the transformation is doing.

1. `transformed_matrix.shape[0] = original_matrix.shape[0]`, meaning number of rows will always remain the same after transformation.
2. `transformed_matrix.shape[1] = len(transformation)`, meaning `transformed_matrix` will have same # of columns as the # of rows in `transformation`.
3. A column `j` in `transformed_matrix` is the horizontal summation of certain columns from `original_matrix`, the column indexes are provided in `transformation[j]`.

How can I do this exact transformation quickly? Such as utilizing matrix multiplication maybe? I'm quite new to numpy, and I've pretty much given all my knowledge from my linear algebra class back to my college professor...

Comment: `transformed_matrix` has 3 columns, `transformation` has 3 rows. I did make a mistake, because `transformation` is not a matrix. So I shouldn't say the shape of `transformation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres the vectorized way of doing this using numpy -

```
original_matrix =np.array([
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
])

transformation = np.array([
    [0, 2],
    [1, 4],
    [3, 6, 7]
])

#transform the tranformation matrix into a 3,8 one hot encoded vector
transformation2 = np.array([np.sum(np.eye(len(original_matrix[0]))[i], axis=0) for i in transformation])

#Dot product the (4,8) and (3,8).T to get the 4,3 matrix
results = np.dot(original_matrix,transformation2.T)
results
```

```
array([[2., 0., 2.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 2., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

The trick is to convert the indices in the transformation into the following -

```
array([[1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1.]])
```

Each row marks the list of columns that need to be added. First row has 1 at 0th and 2nd position for example.

Comment: You are freaking incredible! Is this something I'm gonna get better with over time? I'm starting with ML at work without previous experience. How the hell did you do it so quickly and efficiently, and with this much details?

Comment: Thanks for your kind comments, I would recommend working with numpy and getting a very solid understanding of dot product and element wise transformations. This will help you build vectorized code quite easily. And ofcourse, if you keep at it, shouldnt be long before you can write efficient code yourself :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm gonna spend more time with basics with numpy!